# How correctly to close the cursor Android Java

Tags: java, android

If I try to close the cursor with `onSets.close();` in method `getData()`, the data does not appear in the position. If I do not close the cursor method, then Eclipse complains and says that the base or the cursor is not closed.
But if I add a line `c.moveToFirst();` in the method `getSets(String toexes_ids, String toprog_dif)`, the error does not appear. Why is that? 
 I have two method:

One method in MyDatabase.java

```
public Cursor getSets(String toexes_ids, String toprog_dif) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
  SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();     
  String [] sqlSelect = {"_id", "exes_ids", "sets_ids", "sets_weight", "sets_ones"}; 
  String sqlTables = "Sets";
  String selection = "exes_ids = " + toexes_ids + " AND " + "prog_dif = " + toprog_dif;
  qb.setTables(sqlTables);
  Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, selection, null, null, null, null);
  c.moveToFirst();
  return c;
  }
```

Second method in MainActivity.java

```
public void getData() {
  db = new MyDatabase(this);
  onSets = db.getSets(toexes_ids, toprog_dif);
  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
    R.layout.itemsets, onSets, 
    new String[] {"sets_ids", "sets_weight", "sets_ones"},  
    new int[] {R.id.itemsets_ids, R.id.itemsets_weight, R.id.itemsets_ones});
  listSets.setAdapter(adapter);
  db.close();
    }
```

Error:

```
12-29 16:17:09.335: D/dalvikvm(571): GC_CONCURRENT freed 393K, 53% free 2759K/5767K, external 1574K/1802K, paused 5ms+10ms
12-29 16:17:09.355: E/Database(571): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.exp.exp_betta/databases/fitsdbsqlite3' 
12-29 16:17:09.355: E/Database(571): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
12-29 16:17:09.355: E/Database(571): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `onSets.close()` before `db.close()`?

Comment: Yes, Like `onSets.close(); db.close();`

Comment: Not sure if that will help but it seems your `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor is deprecated: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try to close the database connection as soon as you finished taking data from it. Remained it open makes the database leaked that's why Eclipse throws the Error For not closing DatabaseObjectNotClosedException

```
public Cursor getSets(String toexes_ids, String toprog_dif) {
  SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
  //Querying the database
   db.close(); //as you get the cursor you can now close the connection here.
  return cursor;
 }

public void getData()
 {
  }
```

Comment: **No it is not appropriate at all application crashes!** `12-29 16:53:25.104: I/SQLiteAssetHelper(919): successfully opened database fitsdbsqlite3
12-29 16:53:25.125: E/Cursor(919): Invalid statement in fillWindow()`

Comment: But if I add a line `c.moveToFirst();` in the method `getSets(String toexes_ids, String toprog_dif)`, the error does not appear. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to close the db instance created in getSets() method

Comment: what if you surround code inside getSets with try,catch and finally and close the db instance in the finally, and remove db.close() from getData() method